# Connect to MSSQL Server without setting up ODBC Data Source in QT

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt, qtcore

I have an existing database using MSSQL Server and I want to connect my qt console application in the database. I think MSSQL is not supported by QT is there any chance I could connect my database without setting up ODBC?
Here is my code: 
Btw when I used QMYSQL it says "QMYSQL driver is not loaded".

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("Database_Syncronizer");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("rootpassword");
if(!db.open())
      qDebug()<<"Failed to connect database!";

else{
       qDebug()<<"Successfully connected!";
       testQuery(db);
}
```